# Ubuntu studio 12.04, will not boot

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot, ubuntu-studio

I have an older laptop on which I have been running the current version (I think) of Ubuntu for a few months. I now would like to install Ubuntu Studio, so I made a bootable USB for it.

When I shut down my computer and turned it back on, it booted like normal, not even noticing the bootable USB plugged in.  I'm fairly certain the USB should work, since it appears on my desktop, and the USB has all the right stuff on it.

How can I boot from my LiveUSB?

---

Additional Info:  My computer is a Compaq Presario cq60, with Nvidia graphics and sempron AMD (which I believe is a soundcard). It originally ran Windows Vista.

Answer (score 0):

Try to boot into your BIOS.  Look under boot order or something similar.  Your computer must support boot to USB.  If you don't see this option under the BIOS boot order - your out of luck.

Best,
Tim

Answer (score 0):

To boot from a USB device, you need to either

1. Manually select to boot from the USB each time you boot your computer
2. Set your BIOS (the firmware on the motherboard) to automatically look for a bootable USB device at boot before looking for a hard drive

For option 1, most computers have a button to press when the BIOS screen shows, such as <kbd>F9</kbd>, <kbd>F12</kbd> or a similar key.

For option 2, there will likewise be a button to press (often similar to the keys mentioned above) to access the BIOS options.

---

It should be noted that not all computers, especially older models, have the capabilities to boot from USB devices. You can possibly try installing [Plop Boot Manager](http://www.plop.at/en/bootmanagers.html), or booting from a CD-ROM.